# sass @import issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass

So I've been using sass on my site for a while with no problems.  I've had this working for about a year.

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= depend_on sitewide.css.scss
*/
@import "sitewide.css.scss";
```

Recently I added a gem,  and I seem to recall the sass gem getting updated as a result of installing this new gem (simple_form).

When I went to precompile assets in production,  the import barfed complaining it couldn't find 'sitewide.css.scss'

I had to modify the @import to:

```
@import "app/assets/stylesheets/sitewide.css.scss";
```

To get my assets compiled,  and the production site works fine now.

BUT

Now development is broken!

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
 "/assets/app/assets/stylesheets/sitewide.css.scss"):
 config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:6:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

Development and production have both been bundle updated so all the gems are (should be?) identical

So this has to be an issue with my environments/development.rb???

It contains the following relating to assets config:

```
config.assets.compress = false 
config.assets.debug = true
```

What happened?

Here is bundle show:

- Ascii85 (1.0.2)
- actionmailer (3.2.8)
- actionpack (3.2.8)
- activemodel (3.2.8)
- activerecord (3.2.8)
- activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.10)
- activeresource (3.2.8)
- activesupport (3.2.8)
- addressable (2.3.2)
- afm (0.2.0)
- arel (3.0.2)
- bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
- builder (3.0.4)
- bundler (1.0.21)
- coffee-rails (3.2.2)
- coffee-script (2.2.0)
- coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
- devise (2.0.4)
- erubis (2.7.0)
- execjs (1.4.0)
- hashery (2.1.0)
- hike (1.2.1)
- i18n (0.6.1)
- journey (1.0.4)
- jquery-rails (2.1.4)
- json (1.7.6)
- kaminari (0.14.1)
- libxml-ruby (2.3.3)
- mail (2.4.4)
- mime-types (1.19)
- multi_json (1.5.0)
- mysql2 (0.3.11)
- orm_adapter (0.0.7)
- pdf-reader (1.3.0)
- polyglot (0.3.3)
- prawn (0.12.0)
- rack (1.4.1)
- rack-cache (1.2)
- rack-ssl (1.3.2)
- rack-test (0.6.2)
- rails (3.2.8)
- railties (3.2.8)
- rake (10.0.3)
- rdoc (3.12)
- ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
- sass (3.2.5)
- sass-rails (3.2.5)
- simple_form (2.0.4)
- sprockets (2.1.3)
- thor (0.16.0)
- tilt (1.3.3)
- tiny_tds (0.5.1)
- treetop (1.4.12)
- ttfunk (1.0.3)
- tzinfo (0.3.35)
- uglifier (1.3.0)
- warden (1.1.1)

Comment: Is it normal to have 2 directories named `assets` in your path?  From the error: `/assets/app/assets/stylesheets/sitewide.css.scss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rename your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss and remove the absolut path in your import.

You have to move/rename it. If you leave your old file "applcation.css" in the directory, you will get the same errors. Plain CSS file are not handled the same way as scss or sass files. If you want to use @import feature of scss or sass, you have to change the file extension.

Comment: Hold on,  you were right, I copied application.css to application.css.scss,  but neglected to delete application.css.  Removing application.css made it work!